# Decorate a class with decorator params

Tags: python, class, python-decorators

I'm trying to decorate some class methods but I don't know them names. The decorated class could get some params, also the decorator function; but I'm getting `maximum recursion depth exceed` error and decorator params does not been accessed at inner class definition.

```py
def decorator(decorator_param):
  def wrapper(cls):
    class InnerClass:
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.oInstance = cls(*args, **kwargs)
      def __getattribute__(self, name):
        # decorator validations...
        # here I need the decorator_param ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
        return self.oInstance.__getattribute__(name)
    return InnerClass
  return wrapper

@decorator("a decorator param")
class DecoratedClass():
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
  def say_hello(self):
    print("Hello %s" % self.name)

ie = DecoratedClass(name="cristhiam")
ie.say_hello()
```

I expect use decorator params inside inner class to make some validations if decorated class method can execute or not.

Edit: I'm using django + graphene + JWT. Graphene allows to use django model forms in mutations, but JWT decorates functions only (mutations and form model forms are classes both). I'm trying to decorate with permissions the mutation class. I hope to be clear.

Comment: Can you please explain more about what you are trying to do? give an exact example?

Comment: Hi @ranifisch, thanks for your answer.